# How to create entity related to a class, that derives from Table in Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: database, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to create entity for a table like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table

object TestTable: Table("tests") {
  val id: Column<Long> = long("id").autoIncrement()
  val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 32)

  override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id, name="pk_test_id")
}

class Test (id: EntityID<Long>): Entity<Long>(id) {

}
```

Something like this seems to work:

```
val testId = TestTable.insert {
  it[name] = "test_name_1"
} get TestTable.id
```

Is it possible to create an entity and then insert it? Something, like this?:

```
val testEntity = Test()
...
db.insert(testEntity)
```

I'm not looking for a solution using `IntTable`, `StringTable`, ..., as in the *exposed* documentation. Just with a `Table` from *exposed*.

Answer (score 0):

You can write insert method

```
object TestTable: LongIdTable("tests", columnName = "id") {
    val name = varchar("name", 32)
}

class TestEntity (id: EntityID<Long>): LongEntity(id) {

    companion object: LongEntityClass<TestEntity>(TestTable)

    var name by TestTable.name

}

data class Result(
    val id: Long,
    val name:String
) {

    companion object {
        fun TestEntity.fromEntity(): Result = Result(
            id = id.value,
            name = name
        )

        fun fromRow(row: ResultRow) = Result(
            id = row[TestTable.id].value,
            name = row[TestTable.name]
        )
    }

}


fun insert(result: Result) = transaction {
    return@transaction TestEntity.new {
        this.name = result.name
    }.fromEntity()
}

fun update(result: Result) = transaction {
    return@transaction TestEntity.findById(result.id)?.apply {
        this.name = result.name
    }?.fromEntity()
}

fun firstSelect(name: String) = transaction {
    return@transaction TestEntity.find {
        TestTable.name eq name
    }.map { it.fromEntity() }
}

fun secondSelect(name: String) = transaction {
    return@transaction TestTable.select {
        TestTable.name eq name
    }.map { Result.fromRow(it) }
}
```